# how to use laravel enum, by extra attributes, and localization

Tags: php, laravel, enums

I want use [Ben Sampo Package](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum) for enum in laravel.
this package has a property named 'description' as new property.
but I can't add extra properties(attributes) to my enums.

I want to have an enum 'status' that has a 'isfinal' attribute. to determine if this key is the final or not?

I really need to add some attributes to some enums.
is there any way ?

I checked [this package](https://github.com/archtechx/enums) , too. it's so good and really easy to add extra properties. but I need localization too, and it doesn't have, by default.

Edit:
the enum I need, is something like this:

```
final class Status extends Enum
{
#[Color('red')]
#[Description('Initial status')]
#[IsFinal(false)]    
const Initial = 1;

#[Color('blue')]
#[Description('suspended status')]
#[IsFinal(false)] 
const Pending = 2;

#[Color('white')]
#[Description('completed status')]
#[IsFinal(true)] 
const Completed = 3;

#[Color('red')]
#[Description('canceled status')]
#[IsFinal(true)] 
const Canceled = 4;
 }
```

And then, I want to retrieve the color value, or is final value like this:

```
Status::getColor(1);
```

and

```
Status::Initial->getColor();
```

and

```
$enum->getColor();
```

Update: I have this trait now:

```
   <?php
namespace App\Enums\Concerns;

use BenSampo\Enum\Attributes\Description;
use Exception;

/**
 * Get Enum attributes
 */
trait GetEnumAttributes
{
    public $color;
    public $isFinal;

    public function __construct(mixed $enumValue)
    {
        $this->color = $this->getCustomAttribute($enumValue, 'color');
        $this->isFinal = $this->getCustomAttribute($enumValue, 'is_final');
        $this->description = self::getDescription($enumValue);
        parent::__construct($enumValue);
    }

    protected static function getCustomAttribute(mixed $value, $key)
    {
        $reflection = self::getReflection();
        $constantName = static::getKey($value);
        $constReflection = $reflection->getReflectionConstant($constantName);
        if ($constReflection === false) {
            return null;
        }

        switch ($key) {
            case 'color':
              //  dd( $constReflection->getAttributes(Color::class));
                $customAttributes = $constReflection->getAttributes(Color::class);
                break;
            case 'is_final':
                $customAttributes = $constReflection->getAttributes(IsFinal::class);
                break;
            case 'description':
                    $customAttributes = $constReflection->getAttributes(Description::class);
                    break;
            default:
                $customAttributes = [];
                break;
        }

        return match (count($customAttributes)) {
            0 => null,
            1 => $customAttributes[0]->newInstance()->$key,
            default => throw new Exception('You cannot use more than 1 custom attribute on ' . class_basename(static::class) . '::' . $constantName),
        };
    }
    public static function getCustomInstances()
    {
        return array_map(
            function ($constantValue) {
                $newStatic = new static($constantValue);
                $newStatic = (array) $newStatic;
                $newStatic['description'] = self::getCustomAttribute($constantValue,'description');//getDescription($constantValue);
                $newStatic['color'] = self::getCustomAttribute($constantValue,'color');
                $newStatic['isFinal'] = self::getCustomAttribute($constantValue,'is_final');
                $newStatic = (object) $newStatic;
                return $newStatic;
            },
            static::getConstants(),
        );
    }
```

}

And this happens when I use:

```
dd(Status::getInstances());
```

result:

```
array:4 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\testController.php:19
  "Initial" => App\Enums\Status {#416 ▼
    +value: 1
    +key: "Initial"
    +description: "initial status"
    +color: null
    +isFinal: null
  }
  "Pending" => App\Enums\Status {#418 ▼
    +value: 2
    +key: "Pending"
    +description: "suspended status"
    +color: null
    +isFinal: null
  }
  "Completed" => App\Enums\Status {#421 ▶}
  "Canceled" => App\Enums\Status {#422 ▶}
]
```

I checked the issue, in the 'getCustomAttribute', in case:

```
case 'color':
                dd( $constReflection->getAttributes(Color::class));
                $customAttributes = $constReflection->getAttributes(Color::class);
                break;
```

returns null, however $constReflection has all attributes correctly.
the same happens when I use

```
Status::getCustomInstances();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For BenSampo Package, you can follow a way like this:
Create a Trait:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

/**
 * Get Enum Description
 */
trait GetEnumDescription
{
    private static $thisClass;

    public static function getCustomEnumDescription($enumValue = 0)
    {
        return __(self::getEnumDescription(intval($enumValue)));
    }

    private static function getEnumDescription($enumValue = 0)
    {
        self::$thisClass = static::class;
        $key = self::$thisClass::getKey($enumValue);
        return ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $key));
    }

    public static function getCustomInstances()
    {
        return array_map(
            function ($constantValue) {
                $newStatic = new static($constantValue);
                $newStatic = (array) $newStatic;
                $newStatic['custom_description'] = self::getCustomEnumDescription($constantValue);
                $newStatic = (object) $newStatic;
                return $newStatic;
            },
            static::getConstants(),
        );
    }
}
```

Create an Enum (I usually do enum values with numeric and variable names with snake case. You can customize the methods according to you):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Enums;

use App\Traits\GetEnumDescription;
use BenSampo\Enum\Enum;

/**
 * Menu item types
 */
final class MenuItemType extends Enum
{
    use GetEnumDescription;

    const both = 0;
    const only_customer = 1;
    const only_vendor = 2;
    const closed = 3;
}
```

Make sure you use `GetEnumDescription` Trait. Example instances:

```
// app()->setLocale('tr');
// dd(MenuItemType::getCustomInstances());
// RESULT:
array:4 [▼
  "both" => {#1156 ▼
    +"value": 0
    +"key": "both"
    +"description": "Both"
    +"custom_description": "Her ikisi de"
  }
  "only_customer" => {#1157 ▼
    +"value": 1
    +"key": "only_customer"
    +"description": "Only customer"
    +"custom_description": "Sadece müşteri"
  }
  "only_vendor" => {#1159 ▼
    +"value": 2
    +"key": "only_vendor"
    +"description": "Only vendor"
    +"custom_description": "Sadece bayi"
  }
  "closed" => {#1158 ▼
    +"value": 3
    +"key": "closed"
    +"description": "Closed"
    +"custom_description": "Closed"
  }
]
```

Example:

```php
public static function getCustomInstances()
{
    return array_map(
        function ($constantValue) {
            $newStatic = new static($constantValue);
            $newStatic = (array) $newStatic;
            $newStatic['custom_description'] = self::getCustomEnumDescription($constantValue);
            $newStatic['color'] = 'red';
            $newStatic['is_final'] = true;
            $newStatic = (object) $newStatic;
            return $newStatic;
        },
        static::getConstants(),
    );
}
```

Result:

```php
// after attributes added: dd(MenuItemType::getCustomInstances());
array:4 [▼
  "both" => {#1156 ▼
    +"value": 0
    +"key": "both"
    +"description": "Both"
    +"custom_description": "Her ikisi de"
    +"color": "red"
    +"is_final": true
  }
  "only_customer" => {#1157 ▼
    +"value": 1
    +"key": "only_customer"
    +"description": "Only customer"
    +"custom_description": "Sadece müşteri"
    +"color": "red"
    +"is_final": true
  }
  "only_vendor" => {#1158 ▼
    +"value": 2
    +"key": "only_vendor"
    +"description": "Only vendor"
    +"custom_description": "Sadece bayi"
    +"color": "red"
    +"is_final": true
  }
  "closed" => {#1159 ▼
    +"value": 3
    +"key": "closed"
    +"description": "Closed"
    +"custom_description": "Kapalı"
    +"color": "red"
    +"is_final": true
  }
]
```

**Create two attributes to make it in the structure you want:**

`Color` Attribute:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Attributes;

use Attribute;

#[Attribute(Attribute::TARGET_CLASS_CONSTANT | Attribute::TARGET_CLASS)]
class Color
{
    public function __construct(
        public string $color,
    ) {
    }
}
```

And `IsFinal` Attribute:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Attributes;

use Attribute;

#[Attribute(Attribute::TARGET_CLASS_CONSTANT | Attribute::TARGET_CLASS)]
class IsFinal
{
    public function __construct(
        public bool $is_final,
    ) {
    }
}
```

Here's how I instantiated your enum:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Enums;

use App\Attributes\Color;
use App\Attributes\IsFinal;
use BenSampo\Enum\Attributes\Description;
use BenSampo\Enum\Enum;
use Exception;

/**
 * Menu item types
 */
final class MenuItemType extends Enum
{
    public $color;
    public $isFinal;

    public function __construct(mixed $enumValue)
    {
        $this->color = $this->getCustomAttribute($enumValue, 'color');
        $this->isFinal = $this->getCustomAttribute($enumValue, 'is_final');
        parent::__construct($enumValue);
    }

    protected static function getCustomAttribute(mixed $value, $key)
    {
        $reflection = self::getReflection();
        $constantName = static::getKey($value);
        $constReflection = $reflection->getReflectionConstant($constantName);
        if ($constReflection === false) {
            return null;
        }

        switch ($key) {
            case 'color':
                $customAttributes = $constReflection->getAttributes(Color::class);
                break;
            case 'is_final':
                $customAttributes = $constReflection->getAttributes(IsFinal::class);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return match (count($customAttributes)) {
            0 => null,
            1 => $customAttributes[0]->newInstance()->$key,
            default => throw new Exception('You cannot use more than 1 custom attribute on ' . class_basename(static::class) . '::' . $constantName),
        };
    }

    const both = 0;
    const only_customer = 1;

    #[Color('blue')]
    #[Description('test')]
    #[IsFinal(true)]
    const only_vendor = 2;

    #[Color('red')]
    #[IsFinal(false)]
    const closed = 3;
}
```

Do this by `dd(MenuItemType::getInstances());` The result when I print the screen with:

```
array:4 [▼ // app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php:24
  "both" => App\Enums\MenuItemType {#1156 ▼
    +value: 0
    +key: "both"
    +description: "Both"
    +color: null
    +isFinal: null
  }
  "only_customer" => App\Enums\MenuItemType {#1157 ▼
    +value: 1
    +key: "only_customer"
    +description: "Only customer"
    +color: null
    +isFinal: null
  }
  "only_vendor" => App\Enums\MenuItemType {#1158 ▼
    +value: 2
    +key: "only_vendor"
    +description: "test"
    +color: "blue"
    +isFinal: true
  }
  "closed" => App\Enums\MenuItemType {#1160 ▼
    +value: 3
    +key: "closed"
    +description: "Closed"
    +color: "red"
    +isFinal: false
  }
]
```

Enjoy your work.

Comment: thanks, but where should I define 'custon_description'  value, for all key in enum? I add     #[custom_description('red')]
  but it not work.

Comment: can I use this code for any other attributes? like 'color' , 'isfinal' , ...

Comment: I want to have an enum 'status' that has a 'isfinal' attribute. to determine if this key is the final or not?

Comment: @ERasekh Yes, you can. I've added the color and is_final properties as an example and updated the answer.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: In your wxample, color and isFinal, are the same always. I want define these properties like this : #[Color('red')]   on the above of each enum key I want.

Comment: Ok, you can do this feature by creating Attribute. I'll add an example to the end of my answer shortly.

Comment: I updated my question and add what I want, in a code example. do you know what I means?

Comment: my question is how to add extra attribute? thanks for your quick answers. but I guess you misunderstand.

Comment: thanks @cengsemihsahin. I have created attribute, beside of 'description' in bensampo package. but I didn't what should I do to retrieve this attribute values that is above of enum keys.

Comment: returns null for my two new attributes. you tell getInstances(), but defined getCustomInstances in this morning. now both methods returns null for new attributes.

Comment: You should not use both ways together. Can you share the full content Attribute classes and Enum you created by updating your question?

Comment: I updated, can you please check?

Comment: I'm confusing. I delete my trait, and write code as you, in the enum class. it work's!! why trait not works? is there a trick????

Comment: so beauty! thanks very much. I understood your code and behaviour. and now I can customize it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're over complicating it. An Enum class from this package is a php class like any other so in your case I would advise adding some static methods to the `Status` class which return the appropriate value depending on the input case.

e.g. it might look something like this:

```php
<?php

use BenSampo\Enum\Enum;

final class Status extends Enum
{
    const Initial = 1;
    const Pending = 2;
    const Completed = 3;
    const Canceled = 4;

    public static function getColor(Status $status): string
    {
        return match ($status->value) {
            self::Initial => 'gray',
            self::Pending => 'yellow',
            self::Completed => 'green',
            self::Canceled => 'red',
        };
    }

    public static function isFinal(Status $status): bool
    {
        return in_array($status->value, [self::Completed, self::Canceled]);
    }
 }
```

Which you can then use like this:

```php
$status = Status::Completed();

Status::getColor($status); // "green"
Status::isFinal($status); // true
```

PR's on the package are welcome and considered if they are well thought out and correctly implemented. A more dynamic attribute system may be a good addition.

Comment: thanks but if @cengsemihsahin approach solved my problem, I like that more.

Comment: although, in your method, I can add localization, easily. I think...

Comment: thanks,
in the above post, one programmer solved my problem, and help me to understand your package more.
I can send you a Documentaion update, to add to your guid, if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The BenSampo Laravel Enum package is fantastic for setting up enums with ease in Laravel. However, adding additional custom attributes can be a bit tricky, as it's not natively supported in the package at the moment.

Here are a couple of possible approaches to achieve your goal:

1. Extend the Enum class with custom methods:

You can extend the base Enum class to support additional attributes. However, this requires modifying the Enum class itself, which might not be ideal if you're working in a team or planning on updating the package in the future.

```
    namespace App\Enums;

use BenSampo\Enum\Enum as BaseEnum;

class Enum extends BaseEnum
{
    public static function isFinal($value) {
        // define the logic here
    }
}
```

And then use this base class for your enums:

```
namespace App\Enums;

class Status extends Enum
{
    const DRAFT = 0;
    const FINAL = 1;
    
    public static function getDescription($value): string
    {
        if ($value === self::FINAL) {
            return 'Final';
        }

        return parent::getDescription($value);
    }
}
```

With the above method, you can now check if an enum value is final or not:

```
Status::isFinal(Status::FINAL); // Should return true
```

2. Use additional Enum classes:

Another approach could be to create separate Enums for these special cases. For example, you can have FinalStatus enum class for statuses that are final.

```
namespace App\Enums;

use BenSampo\Enum\Enum;

final class FinalStatus extends Enum
{
    const PUBLISHED = 1;
    // Add more final statuses here
}
```

You can then use Laravel's localization features to handle the localization of your enums. You would create language files for each language you want to support, and use the __() function in your application code to retrieve the localized string.

In any case, the cleanest solution would be to have the package support additional attributes natively. You might consider creating an issue or a pull request on the package's GitHub repository to see if the maintainers would be open to such a feature.

Comment: thanks, I edited my question and add code. I want to write code as it.

Comment: about package issue, yes I sent an issue first, but he closed it without any proper answer that solve my problem.

Comment: https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum/issues/314